# Paypal customer partner-referrals Api integration redirect back url parameter mismatch

Tags: redirect, paypal, integration, optional-parameters, url-parameters

I have used node as back-end and angularjs as front-end

I want to integrate Paypal customer partner-referrals API in my system.

API details as below:

```
${apiUrl}/v1/customer/partner-referrals
```

Response Redirect Back URL with parameters:

```
${AppUrl}/paypal/redirect/?
merchantId=123
&merchantIdInPayPal=PIROWETSFRTDD
&permissionsGranted=true
&consentStatus=true
&productIntentId="addipmt"
&productIntentID=addipmt
&isEmailConfirmed=true
&accountStatus=BUSINESS_ACCOUNT
```

> Issue: It send "productIntentId" and "productIntentID" both and also not getting "returnMessage" in Redirect Back URL.

According to this documentation it should return "returnMessage" in URL parameters.

[Payal sample response](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/commerce-platform/v1/onboarding/upfront/?mark=v1%2Fcustomer%2Fpartner-referrals#response-sample)